# Vue - How to pass data to child component after route is entered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hey I'm relatively new to vue.js.
I have a Home.vue which creates a data array after successful login and entering the route.

I tried it with

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    ***
    <History :data="this.cData" />
    ***
  </div>
</template>

***

 beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(async (vm) => {
      vm.cData = await vm.select(vm.handle);
      console.log(vm.cData);
    });
  },
```

But the data is send before `beforeRouteEnter()` and the History component needs it for creating itself.
Is there a way do to it?

Comment: You can't add your `beforeRouterEnter()` in a vue.js properties, like created or computed ?

Answer (score 0):

If the History component needs it for creating itself, then you should defer creation of the component (with `v-if`) until `cData` is ready. `cData` should be declared upfront in the `data` object with value `null`.

You're also doing `this.cData` in the template but it should be just `cData`.

```html
<History v-if="cData" :data="cData" />
```